# Problem Mapping a Sharepoint folder to a drive in Windows XP

Tags: sharepoint

I can map a folder on sharepoint from a Windows Vista machine with the following command line

```
NET USE z: "http://srv-nam/sites/folder-1/folder-2"
```

...and it works just fine.

If I then logon with exactly the same user to a Windows XP box and type exactly the same command I get

```
Failed with system error 67; Network name cannot be found
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I get the Windows XP box working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely enough the solution to this was to put my sharepoint URL into tinyurl.com.  The resulting tinyurl URL I used in the net use command and everything worked fine.

Note that this 'solution' then broke when running on Windows Vista machines, so I had to do a check in the batch file I was using to figure out which version of Windows I was running on and change the mapping appropriately.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Vista & 7 support WebDav over HTTPS out of the box, Windows XP is a bit trickier. Read
  http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html
for details . If I add a 'Network Place' via 'My Network Places' then I am able to mount a Sharepoint folder in my XP box.

HTH,

JJK

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the link, but I'm pretty sure that this is not HTTPS related as my server is not configured to support HTTPS.  Neither the browser interface nor the command line mapping from Vista work if I try https.  I will have a go at the Network Place mapping to see if that helps.